Counter-example for image of the intersection = intersection of the image
we know that if f is injective then $f(A \cap B) = f(A) \cap f(B)$ for all $A$ and $B$ subsets of $X$ being the domain of $f$.
I want to prove that the reciprocal is false, so ideally give an example of a non injective function $f$ for which the equality is held for all $A$ and $B$ subsets of domain $X$ of $f$.
Can you give such an example?

I thought about the absolute value of x on IR, quite hard for the case a=-b

Such an example is not possible.
If $f$ is not injective there exists two different elements $a,b\in X$ with $f(a)=f(b)$, but then
$$
f(\{a\}\cap\{b\})=f(\emptyset)=\emptyset.
$$
While $f(\{a\})\cap f(\{b\})$ is clearly non empty.

Why you think, that $X$ empty helps? (empty function is injective).

Your reasoning is nice, however I'm looking for f non injective for which the statement is true FOR all A, B subsets.

@zkutch You're right, I think I was confused because for the empty function we always have $f(A\cap B)=f(A)\cap f(B)$, but that doesn't really matters. I'll edit the answer.

@user1478012 The point of my answer is to show that what you're looking for does not exist, that is, if $f(A\cap B)=f(A)\cap f(B)$ for every pair of $A,B\subset X$ then $f$ is injective.

So you confirm it's an if and only if? Can you prove rigourously?
